Adding buttons to the dialog header
I want to add two buttons to a dialog header in my Oracle APEX application.

One would go just to the left of the button that closes the dialog with a little bit of padding between the two.  Extra credit for enlarging the "dialog close" button so that it is the same size as the button added

The second button would go in the top right corner of the dialog page


In other words one button before the ui-dialog-title element and one button after it.  I have some javascript code I found that will place a button to the right of the window close:


$('.ui-dialog-titlebar', window.parent.document).append('<button type="button" class="t-Button">Button Name</button>');

$('.someIdentifier', window.parent.document).click(function(){

    console.log('button is clicked');

});



By changing the .ui-dialog-titlebar parameter you can change which element to place the button immediately after but I feel that a function that places html code immediately before an element rather than appending it would help solve my problem.

You might consider creating a new modal page template( duplicating the theme's default modal window template is the easiest way). Then make the HTML changes on header section of the template.

@cengiz sevimli — I would strongly discourage anything modal. Such things contaminate sites. It's good that they are rarely used.

I'm not familiar with oracle-apex, but this looks like jQuery, although you haven't tagged it. If it is jQuery, have you considered prepend()?

the desired functionality in your Oracle APEX application, you can use JavaScript to dynamically insert buttons into the dialog header
!.Waits for the dialog to be created before modifying its structure.
2.Created using jQuery and inserted just before the dialog-close button.
Padding margin right is added for spacing.
3.Dynamically adjusts the size of the dialog's close button to match the custom button.
4.Positioned absolutely in the top-right corner of the dialog title using CSS.
5.Buttons inherit styling from -button, ensuring consistency with the Oracle APEX theme.
